# can't render thead or tfoot tags in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

According to [this post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms227996(v=vs.100).aspx)

> When you create a Table object, include the TableHeaderRow and
>   TableHeaderCell controls. The default values of the TableHeaderRow and
>   TableFooterRow controls **cause the control to render thead, tbody, and
>   tfoot elements**

I have been trying to get the `thead` and `tfoot` tags to render without success.

I am using the classes mentioned in that link I posted and I only get `tbody` with a bunch of nested `tr` tags. I am using VS2012 pro and .net 4.5.

What am I doing wrong?

```
public void BuildHTMLTable(DataTable dt)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    Table tbl = new Table();

    // create table header
    TableHeaderRow thr = new TableHeaderRow();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        TableHeaderCell thc = new TableHeaderCell();
        thc.Text = col.Caption;
        thr.Cells.Add(thc);
    }
    tbl.Rows.AddAt(0, thr);

    // write out each data row
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        foreach (var value in row.ItemArray)
        {
            TableCell td = new TableCell();
            td.Text = value.ToString();
            tr.Controls.Add(td);
        }
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
    }

    // Create table footer
    TableFooterRow tfr = new TableFooterRow();
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        TableCell th = new TableCell();
        th.Text = col.Caption;
        tfr.Cells.Add(th);
    }
    tbl.Rows.Add(tfr);

    // Renter the table to html writer
    tbl.RenderControl(w);
    // copy html writer to a string variable
    tableString = sw.ToString();
}
```

**rendered HTML below**

[image: rendered html]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the TableSection value of the TableHeaderRow and TableFooterRow.

```
public void BuildHTMLTable(DataTable dt)
{
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
    HtmlTextWriter w = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

    Table tbl = new Table();

    // create table header
    TableHeaderRow thr = new TableHeaderRow();
    thr.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader; // ADD THIS LINE

    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        TableHeaderCell thc = new TableHeaderCell();
        thc.Text = col.Caption;
        thr.Cells.Add(thc);
    }
    tbl.Rows.AddAt(0, thr);

    // write out each data row
    foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
    {
        TableRow tr = new TableRow();
        foreach (var value in row.ItemArray)
        {
            TableCell td = new TableCell();
            td.Text = value.ToString();
            tr.Controls.Add(td);
        }
        tbl.Rows.Add(tr);
    }

    // Create table footer
    TableFooterRow tfr = new TableFooterRow();
    tfr.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableFooter; // ADD THIS LINE
    foreach (DataColumn col in dt.Columns)
    {
        TableCell th = new TableCell();
        th.Text = col.Caption;
        tfr.Cells.Add(th);
    }
    tbl.Rows.Add(tfr);

    // Renter the table to html writer
    tbl.RenderControl(w);
    // copy html writer to a string variable
    tableString = sw.ToString();
}
```

Comment: See updated answer.  Mind you, I'm not sure why TableHeaderRow and TableFooterRow don't have this set by default.

Comment: Thank you. That did it. I agree I'm not sure why it isn't a default. You rock!